# Rails 3.0 Sending Email Error: Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write a method to send out emails to all members on my website. Everything seems to go well and the I get a message saying something went wrong. I checked my production file and I got the following message:

```
 Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
```

The app was able to send out approximately 15 emails before it encountered this error.

Not sure if it helps, but this is my controller code:

```
 def sendLatestEmail
accounts = Account.all
latestFive = Opinion.find(
    :all,
    :order => "created_at DESC",
    :limit => 5
)
accounts.each do |a|
    if a.allow_email_notification
        AdminMailer.latest_email(a, latestFive).deliver
    end
end
flash[:message] = "Latest Emails Delivered"
redirect_to(admin_panel_path)
end
```

In my production.rb file I have something like the following:

```
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address              => "smtpout.secureserver.net",
   :port                 => 80,
   :domain               => 'somesite.com',
   :user_name            => 'no-reply@somesite.com',
   :password             => 'password',
   :authentication       => 'login',
   :enable_starttls_auto => false 
}
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

I have an email account set up with godaddy, so I'm not sure if there is some kind of limit on the amount of emails you can send out?

I've been looking into simpleworker, but I want to make sure I'm not wasting my money if I can fix this problem on my own.

Thank you,

Brian

Comment: Are you sure you have set right port number?

Comment: That is the port number that godaddy advised me to configure it under.

Comment: Usually, SMTP port is 25 and/or 2525.

Comment: As others already pointed out 80 is not a common port for SMTP, but if you are able to deliver even a single mail SMTP settings should be fine and are not a problem. This error generally appears when the other end do not want to communicate with your server, because of either authentication problems or connection timeout or user pressing stop button in the browser. You can google around to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 for SMTP outbound is a little odd (25 is the typical port), but if it was passing mail successfully... Appears to be a server issue - don't see any issues with the code.

FWIW, I have stopped trying to use SMTP and now use http://postmarkapp.com/. Their pricing is ridiculously competitive, and it drops into ActionMailer with two lines of configuration (no changes to your actual code) with their gem. Not affiliated, just passing it along as I have spent more than enough of my life trying to get various SMTP services to play ball.

Comment: Yes - Postmark avoids the use of SMTP altogether. They provide an API that you can post messages to, and a gem that handles all of the integration since you are already using ActionMailer. See https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-rails#readme

Comment: Hi Brian, if this answer was helpful, if you could accept it, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Long message sending jobs should definitely be done in a background job, but you can also fork off that code with Kernel.fork, having a block of code that keeps on running, although it can  lead to some weird stuff sometimes.

Some things to check:

Yeah, port 80 for smtp sounds a little bit weird, does any emails actually end up being delivered?

If you run the code in the rails console, does it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

i updated the server with mongrel, and its working fine..webrick sometimes is unable to decode the Long message sending jobs.